# Facebook Graph API Gender

Tags: facebook, cordova, facebook-graph-api

Hi I have problem with Facebook Graph API. I'm using it in cordova with this plugin: https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4 (I think is not important)

The main problem is value gender. When system language is English I get following value:

```
gender: "male"
```

but when my system language is Czech I get following value:

```
gender: "muž"
```

and this is problem for me because I expecting for future work "male" or "female"

does anyone now how to figure it out and get always english?

Thanks for any answer

Comment: is it possible to share the login code, I have been trying to make it work for a month and still no use. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to add the locale to the API call, it would be like this for english:

```
/me?fields=gender&locale=en_US
```

Or with the Cordova plugin:

```
facebookConnectPlugin.api('/me?fields=gender&locale=en_US', ...)
```

Answer (score 2):

See [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api) for more information about how to use the Graph API.
Written under "Modifying API Requests":

**locale**
Used if your app needs the ability to retrieve localized content in the language of a particular locale (when available).

So try to set the `locale` parameter to english.

Comment: Thanks for answer. actually I found this article before but I have no idea how to include this parameter to Graph API request.